# How do I edit a custom font's size in Skyrim SSE?

Tags: fonts, fontforge

I was able to install a custom font (Calibri standard) into Skyrim SSE by creating a swf file and a custom fontconfig.txt. However, the font is too large and in some places it cuts off part of the word.

I looked online and found a Reddit post saying to transform the font using FontForge. I used FontForge to scale the font down to 80% and the font looks completely different (see screenshot). Is there a better way to accomplish this or am I doing something wrong in FontForge?

https://imgur.com/a/UQyv1Gl

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, solution is the following:

1. Select all
2. Element -> Simplify -> Simplify
3. Element -> Transformations -> Transform...
4. Origin: Glyph Origin
5. Make sure "Round to Int" is checked
6. Scale Uniformly to desired scale